# Retrieve Pixel Color from Tapped Image Source in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pixel

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and would like to retrieve the color of a pixel from an image that is set as the source directly in XAML. The user interaction is triggered by tapping on the image. I have explored using TapGestureRecognizer and DependencyService for platform-specific implementations.

**XAML:**

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="your_image_source.jpg">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnImageTappedCommand}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**C# (Xamarin.Forms):**

```
public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
{
    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(OnImageTapped)
        });
    }

    private void OnImageTapped()
    {
        // Need guidance on how to retrieve the pixel color here
        // using DependencyService or any other suitable method.
    }
}
```

**Platform-Specific Interface (IPixelColorService):**

```
public interface IPixelColorService
{
    Color GetPixelColor(object imageSource, int x, int y);
}
```

**Platform-Specific Implementation (Android):**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PixelColorService))]

namespace YourNamespace.Droid
{
    public class PixelColorService : IPixelColorService
    {
        public Color GetPixelColor(object imageSource, int x, int y)
        {
            // Implement platform-specific code to get the pixel color at (x, y) in the image
            // ...

            // For now, just returning a random color for demonstration purposes
            return Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeking guidance on how to implement the OnImageTapped method to retrieve the pixel color from the tapped position in the image, where the image source is set directly in XAML. I would like to use DependencyService or any other suitable method. Any code samples or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

my c# winforms code:

```
((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)
```

my c# code-behined:

```
public SKColor GetPixel(int x, int y);
private void mousemove(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    return GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skbitmap.getpixel?view=skiasharp-2.88

Comment: ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0501 'MainPage.GetPixel(int, int)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial BeautyFly C:\Users\user\Desktop\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\BeautyFly\MainPage.xaml.cs 27 Active```

Comment: please [edit] your question to show the code and any errors/exceptions.  Just posting an error in the comments without any context makes it impossible to help you

Comment: @Jason Question edited.

Comment: `GetPixel` is a method of `SKBitmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private async void pixels()
        {
            Stream imageStream = null;
            if (picturebox.Source is FileImageSource fileImageSource)
            {
                string filePath = fileImageSource.File;
                imageStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            }
            else if (picturebox.Source is UriImageSource uriImageSource)
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    byte[] imageDate = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uriImageSource.Uri);
                    imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageDate);
                }
            }
            byte[] imageData = null;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await imageStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                imageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < imageData.Length; i += 4)
            {
                imageData[i] = (byte)Math.Min(255, imageData[i] + 10); // Blue
                imageData[i + 1] = (byte)Math.Min(255, imageData[i + 1] + 10); // Green
                imageData[i + 2] = (byte)Math.Min(255, imageData[i + 2] + 10); // Red and [i + 3] for Alpha
            }
            using (MemoryStream manipulatedStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
            {
                picturebox.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => manipulatedStream);
            }
        }
```

In this code i used picturebox as your `Image` and then added a number of 10 to each RGB of all of pixels in `picturebox.Source`.

Comment: how would this work for any compressed image format?